# Variable inspection in Visual Studio 2008 in asp.net IronPython inside a class

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ironpython

I need to inspect the value of a variable inside a class in asp.net IronPython in Visual Studio 2008. Visual Studio 2008 inspector doesnt work for IronPython (if the inspector works in VS 2008 for asp.net IronPython and it isnt working for me plz tell me) and you can't use Response.write - Response.end inside a class. What can I do to know the variable's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to dig into the object's dictionary.  This should be the **dict** field on the object.  If the variable is in the class instead you'll need to dig into the **class** and then into the classes dictionary.  Unfortunately it's rather painful to do right now.

This is already improved for a future release of IronPython - checked into the current source tree (which will likely become 2.6.1) there's support via debugger proxies which make this much better.  So if you're using 2.6 and are willing to build from source you could grab the current sources and give that a go.

Comment: Thank you Dino. Forgive me my ignorance, I see you are highly involved with IronPython, who are you exactly?

Comment: And core developer of IronPython?

Comment: Yes, I'm a core developer of IronPython and I've worked on the DLR in the past.

Comment: Being cPython and .NET popular language/framework here, and having spanish around 330 million speakers in 21 countries, it would be cool to see more material of IronPython in spanish :)